# How can I model a tap shape?

Tags: modeling

I am facing an issue modeling this shape. Any clue?
[image: Target Shape]

This is as far as I could get:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help http://topologyguides.com

Comment: Select the top of the base you have made and extrude up. Select the side of the new extrusion and extrude it outwards.

Comment: @sambler: Not quite what I am looking for, but thanks.

Answer (score 4):

My finished model looks like this. Of course topology may be different- it's your decision how you set the edge flows. Here's the .blend for you to study: [image]
[image]

It's too broad modeling task to describe every step, that's why I used a screencast keys in my .gifs. Begin with extruding the cube horizontaly, then subdivide it using edge loops (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Add a *circle* (with 8 vertices) and bridge the extruded cube's end with it (<kbd>W</kbd>-->*LoopTools*-->*Bridge*). Your base mesh is ready. Rest is a matter of using blender modeling tools to tweak some vertices as pictured below.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Mashaa Allah Tabarak Allah, this is awesome.

Answer (score -2):

Try extruding the top, rotating, and extruding again to make the handle then alter it in sculpt mode.

Comment: I am trying to find an easiest way. Sculpting is a tool I want to avoid on this model. But I will give it a try. Thanks though.